# Match first and last name only if it doesn't start with "S"

Tags: regex

Write a Regex that saves each first name in one capture group and the last name in the other, only if they both do not start with `S`.

```
Anna Springer
Ian Vaughan
Maria Hamilton
Natalie Knox
Bernadette Hill
Dylan Welch
Michelle Lee
Sally Lee
Eric Ellison
Dan Kerr
```

Comment: any attempts? Which lang you're running?

Comment: Who hasn't to start with S, first or second name?

Comment: i'm trying if for an hour now. It is just simple regex.

Comment: both shouldn't start with S

Comment: Like this: [`(?m)^([A-RT-Z][a-z]*) ([A-RT-Z][a-z]*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/iX9pX1/2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!S)([A-Z][a-z]*) (?!S)([A-Z][a-z]*)$
```

Explanation:

1. We want to match only the entire line, hence we enclose everything with `^$` (*start* and *end* of line).
2. `(?!S)` - don't start with `S`.
3. `([A-Z][a-z]*)` - capital letter, followed by lowercase letters.

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/qL5gG9/1)

Comment: I use this tool: http://labs.odindecisions.com/Tools/RegexAnalyzer.aspx         It doesn't give me the desired result, I can't really get why

Comment: @skofield, try the one suggested by the tool you are currently using - [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qL5gG9/1). I am not sure what language and flags your tool uses.